# how to pass dynamic table name and get query return result data using postgres function?

Tags: postgresql

I created a function to get the records from a dynamically passed table.

which is as follow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_rec(tbl_name text)
  RETURNS SETOF text AS   -- text!!
$func$
BEGIN 
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
        'SELECT * FROM %I'
       , tbl_name);
   RETURN;
END 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and selected like this :

```
SELECT public.get_rec((mytablename)); -- passed my table name
```

but it is giving an error like this :

```
   the column "my table name" does not exist
```

does anyone know how to do this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Something looks wrong here.  In theory your code should work.  But as it stands it is not very useful.  It can only be called on a table that has just one column of type text.  Have you checked that you are passing the correct table name?

Comment: I also used return type as record but for that i have to pass column name when i called this function like 'select * from function () as (co1 _datatype,col2 datatype)', which is no use to make it dynamic if i have to specify the column. i want to pass dynamic table name !

Comment: If your tables have different columns with different types, you cannot have a generic function to call the contents.  PostgreSQL does not allow this.